# Can't find an icon to launch Ubuntu Tweak on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, launcher, ubuntu-tweak

I've installed Ubuntu Tweak on Ubuntu 14.04 and I can only run it by going to the terminal and typing `ubuntu-tweak`.

There's no icon in the drop down menu. I installed GNOME flashback so I am just trying to get a launcher icon somewhere in the launcher. It's not in system settings either.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1) Installed right ?

First, let's reinstall the package :

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tualatrix/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

---

#### 2) Desktop file

If that didn't work, let's make sure Ubuntu Tweak installed his `.desktop` (launcher, kind of).

Please verify if you have the output "yes" with the commandline :

```
[ -e /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop ] && echo yes || echo no
```

- if the output is "yes", you can try :

  ```
    sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop
  ```
- if the output is "no", or if it still doesn't work, then, do this commandline :

  ```
    sudo wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ENWxyiPU -O /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop && sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop
  ```

---

#### 3) Manually add a menu entry

If both methods did not worked, we're going to try to manually add a shortcut. You'll need `alacarte`:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
alacarte
```

Create a new menu entry :

```
Name: Ubuntu-Tweak
Command :  ubuntu-tweak
Icon : /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/ubuntu-tweak.png
```

Comment: @user281745 - if the answer worked please accept it as the answer.